# detecting http requests coming from an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, iframe

okay, my scenario is that i have an iframe on a page, that is calling a url on a different domain.  This url sometimes will tunnel (not a full redirect) to a different url than the one i'm calling.  I know I cannot look at the contents of the iframe, since I'm calling a different domain, but is there any way to detect that the url tunneled to a different url than the src property of the iframe?  For example, is there a way to detect the http requests that are coming from a page?

IF the url is tunneled to a different url, then I need to redirect the user off the current page, because that means their session has expired (i know this doesn't make much sense, and there should be a much better way of detecting a session is dead, but this is the only way I have to do this right now).

Comment: That's forbidden by same-origin policy http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/28/explaining-same-origin-policy-part-1-deny-read.aspx, modulo some hackery (e.g. you can usually see the length of the .frames collection off a child frame).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you can hook onto in a "different origin" iframe is the onload event of the iframe itself. For anything else, you'll need a plug-in.

Comment: When you say a plug-in, do you mean like a jquery plug-in?

Comment: No - that's a javascript LIBRARY. This needs an actual plug-in for the browser itself.

Answer (score 1):

Download Fiddler and configure your browser, it will show all HTTP requesting going through your application. You can also install firebug extension in Firefox and check the HTTP rquests in the "Net" tab of Firebug.

Using Fiddler to capture the cross domain requests
http://blog.caplin.com/2010/03/19/using-fiddler-to-help-develop-cross-domain-capable-javascript-web-applications/

Comment: http://blog.caplin.com/2010/03/19/using-fiddler-to-help-develop-cross-domain-capable-javascript-web-applications/

Comment: I'm actually needing this to happen on the page as a user is using the site.  if the iframe tries to load its src, and that url is tunneled to a different url, then I need to redirect the page to a different page.  this has to happen in real time as a user is on the page...